# How to find only Grandparent records where all grandchildren match some criteria in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following Models with these relations

Project has_many Tasks

Task has_many TodoItems

I want to perform a search which returns only Projects where all it's Tasks have all their TodoItems marked as done

I've tried adding to Project has_many :todo_items, through: :tasks

and then doing this

`projects = Projects.joins(:todo_items).where(todo_items: {done: true})`

but that'll returns Projects where some of the todo items are done whereas I only want projects where all of the todo items have been marked as done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with left joins.

I will show you how to get to the most activerecord-like code, starting from raw SQL, fixing it on the fly and increasing more and more the abstraction level. This might probably help you in some other similar task in the future.

Let's start with the simplest SQL that could work (actually it doesn't).

```sql
SELECT `projects`.`*`, 
       `tasks`.`*`, 
       `todo_items`.`*`
FROM `projects`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tasks`
  ON `tasks`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `todo_items`
  ON `todo_items`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id
  AND NOT `todo_items`.`done`
WHERE `todo_items`.`id` IS NULL
;
```

This will join the three tables, under the specified conditions. If you need an easy way to understand joins, you can imagine that the result is all the combinations of rows from the three tables, provided that the conditions in the `ON` parts are satisfied.

The fundamental fact of LEFT joins is that whenever there is no match for some row in the left, the DB ensures that a result is given, with NULL on the right.

Forgetting about the specific columns, you can imagine that this query would return:

```
(p1, NULL, NULL)        -- project with no tasks
(p2, t2_1, NULL)        -- project with three tasks, first is complete
(p2, t2_2, todo2_2_1)   -- this task has one pending todo
(p2, t2_3, todo2_3_1)   -- this task has two pending todos
(p2, t2_3, todo2_3_2)
(p3, t3_1, NULL)        -- project with two complete tasks
(p3, t3_2, NULL)
...
```

Here there is the reason for using `AND NOT todo_items.done` in the `ON` clause. Whenever a task has only completed TODO, it will appear with `NULL` todo. When a task has some incomplete TODO it will appear with its data. On the other side, if task `t2_2` had any completed todo_item, it wouldn't be returned.

Now the original query is failing, because `p2` that has one complete task will be returned, despite having another task which is not complete.

But there is a nice SQL function that you can use to actually check for not-nulls:

```sql
SELECT `projects`.`*`,
       COUNT(`todo_items`.`id`) AS `pending_todo_count`
FROM `projects`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tasks`
  ON `tasks`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `todo_items`
  ON `todo_items`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id
  AND NOT `todo_items`.`done`
GROUP BY `projects`.`*`
;
```

With the above data, this will return something like

```
(p1, 0)        -- project with no tasks
(p2, 3)        -- project with three tasks, first is complete
(p3, 0)        -- project with two complete tasks
...
```

Now we skip the ones that have incomplete TODOs

```sql
SELECT `projects`.`*`
FROM `projects`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tasks`
  ON `tasks`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `todo_items`
  ON `todo_items`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id
  AND NOT `todo_items`.`done`
GROUP BY `projects`.`*`
HAVING COUNT(`todo_items`.`id`) = 0
;
```

You can see that we have taken off the column in SELECT and added a condition on the grouping. This query is finally right, it will return

```
(p1)
(p3)
```

---

So now we need ruby code for it, if you are in Rails 5 you are lucky, because left joins are supported directly, provided you define an association for 'pending_todo_items' in Task:

```rb
class Task
  has_many :pending_todo_items, -> { where(done: false) }, class_name: 'TodoItem'
end


Project.
  left_joins(tasks: :pending_todo_items).
  group(Project.arel_table[:id]).
  having(TodoItem.arel_table[:id].count.eq(0))
```

The argument to `group` and `having` are from Arel, which is just one level of abstraction below ActiveRecord, to avoid the use of hardcoded strings like

```
Project.
  left_joins(tasks: :pending_todo_items).
  group('projects.id').
  having('COUNT(todo_items.id) = 0')
```

which will break as soon as the model <-> tablename mapping changes.

If you are in Rails 4 or less, you have to write the left join by hand or through Arel:

```
Project.
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN .........').
  group('projects.id').
  having('COUNT(todo_items.id) = 0')
```

---

*UPDATE*

You can also use `NULLIF` to convert the `done` column (1/0) into a `pending` column (NULL/notnull), this way you can avoid special scoped associations (although I definitely see that they can be useful):

```sql
SELECT `projects`.`*`
FROM `projects`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tasks`
  ON `tasks`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `todo_items`
  ON `todo_items`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id
GROUP BY `projects`.`*`
HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(`todo_items`.`done`, 1)) = 0
;
```

The `NULLIF(`todo_items`.`done`, 1)` expression returns `NULL` for done items, and `0` (the original value) for pending items.

In ActiveRecord, you would have to patch predications for ease of use:

```
module Arel::Predications
  def null_if(other)
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('NULLIF', [self, other])
  end
end

Project.
  left_joins(tasks: :todo_items).
  group(Project.arel_table[:id]).
  having(TodoItem.arel_table[:done].null_if(true).count.eq(0))
```

Comment: that worked a treat, thanks for the detailed well explained answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to join both tasks and todo_items:

```
projects = Projects.joins(tasks: :todo_items)
```

Then let's talk about the condition: 
I do not know, if it is possible in Activerecord syntax, so I'd think of SQL.

If it is one-time operation, I would do iteration in ruby like this:

```
# not production code, very expensive
projects = Projects.joins(tasks: todo_items).all.select { |project| project.tasks.any? { |task| task.todo_items.all?(&:done) } }
```

If you need to call it often, I'd create cache:

```
rails g migration AddAllDoneToTasks all_done:boolean{null: false}

class Task
  before_save :set_all_done
  def set_all_done
    self.all_done = todo_items.all?(&:done)
  end
end

class TodoItem
  belongs_to :task, touch: true
end
```

Then the search is quite easy:

```
Projects.joins(:tasks).where.not(all_done: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find task list, having at least 1 todo_item which is not done,

```
tasks_not_done = Task.joins(:todo_items).where(todo_items: { done: false }).ids
```

Get your project for which tasks are not listed in `tasks_not_done`

```
 projects = Project.joins(:tasks).where.not(tasks: { id: tasks_not_done })
```

Comment: I would recommend skipping the `ids` part or at least using `select(:id)`. `ids` uses `pluck` which returns an `Array` where as the other 2 options will just create a subquery